# Deforming parametric circle

Tags: differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, parametric

I have a circle given by parametric equations:

$x = \sin(t)$

$y = \cos(t)$

I wan't to apply some transformation to that circle so that it becomes some other curve (no longer a circle), but it's still closed (at $t=2*\pi$, $x$ and $y$ have same values as at $t=0$), continuous and as $t$ changes the $x$ and $y$ traces the curve with the same speed as it did when the curve was a circle.

Not sure how to write this ... maybe

$$
    \sqrt{\left( \frac{dx}{dt} \right)^2+\left( \frac{dy}{dt} \right)^2} = constant
$$

should be constant and the same after applying transformation as before applying transformation.

Best thing would be a whole family of such transformations so that by choosing some parameters I can vary between undistorted circle and more distorted circle and differently distorted circle.

Examples of curves that might be result of the transformation that I seek are some ellipse of the same circumference as the initial circle. Or some other curve, where parts of it are moved closer to the center and some further from the center than they were in the case of the circle.

Comment: In what way do you wish to distort your circle? As it stands, this is far too broad to have any sensible answer.

Comment: Certainly $\dfrac{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}{dt}$ makes no sense. What are you actually thinking of?

Comment: I think he is trying to express that he wants a constant speed. Perhaps he wants $\sqrt{\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2}=c$

Comment: @TedShifrin I wan't exactly what user tomi described. Constant speed, same as in case of parametric circle.

Comment: @Servaes Change its shape in any way, so that it's no longer a circle. But I need the resulting curve to still be closed, continuous and have the same constant speed as in case of the circle. Preferably it also must be expressible through equations, not just by numerical approximation.

Comment: Note that any parametric curve can be reparametrized to constant speed. So that requirement is equivalent to the length of the distorted curve being $2\pi$. Of course any closed curve (that has a well-defined length) can be scaled to have this length.

Comment: Also, there is no nice closed form for the circumference of a general ellipse. So even determining whether an ellipse still has the same circumference as your original circle is intractible.

Comment: Would a pair of parallel segments connected by semicircles at the two ends do? They could be written with piecewise defined functions using the segment length as a parameter.

Comment: @EthanBolker Cool idea! I think it will work! I'll just need to carefully define the segments to keep the speed constant and same but it definitely can be done.

Comment: Glad that might work.  The segments can be vertical or horizontal easily. With a little more work you could have them make an arbitrary angle with the $x$-axis. You can post an answer here to your own question.

Comment: @Servaes Very good point about altering any parametric curve to achieve constant speed and scaling the curve to have a correct length. Do you know any 'easy' parametric curves with easy to calculate length and easy to calculate speed, so that they can be altered to achieve constant speed? Ellipse doesn't seem to be good candidate. Maybe something like `x=sin(a*t)*sin(t), y=sin(a*t)*cos(t)`? Is it easy to calculate length of such curve?

Comment: @EthanBolker If you post this as the answer, even with just a gist of the idea, I'll gladly accept it. I don't think anything better (and easier) comes up and your idea is very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a pair of parallel segments joined at the ends by semicircles.

[image]

To keep the circumference at $2\pi$ you want
$$
2\pi r + 2L = 2\pi
$$
so
$$
L = \pi(1-r)
$$

The illustration is $r \approx 1/2$.

You could easily make the stretched circle vertical. Or add both vertical and horizontal segments to make something squarish. With a little more work the axis of symmetry could be at any angle.